# How to display a success or error message after submitting the form? Using react

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I'm using the Storage location to store data and I want to display a success message if the data has been stored or an error message if the data has not been stored.

code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Form } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import '../css/Cadastrar.css'
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

const Cadastrar = ({ pacientes, setPacientes }) => {
    const [pacienteInfo, setPacienteInfo] = useState({
        nome: "",
        dataDeNascimento: "",
        cpf: "",
        sexo: "",
        endereco: "",
    });
    const [disable, setDisable] = useState(false);
    const [checkCpf, setCheckCpf] = useState({
        errorMessageCpf: "",
    });
    const handleFieldChange = (event) => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        setPacienteInfo({
            ...pacienteInfo,
            [name]: value
        });
    }
    const onFormSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (!pacienteInfo) return;
        setPacientes([...pacientes, {
            id: Date.now(),
            nome: pacienteInfo.nome.trim(),
            dataDeNascimento: pacienteInfo.dataDeNascimento,
            cpf: pacienteInfo.cpf,
            sexo: pacienteInfo.sexo,
            endereco: pacienteInfo.endereco.trim(),
            status: true
        }]);
        setPacienteInfo({ nome: '', dataDeNascimento: '', cpf: '', sexo: '', endereco: '' });
    };
    //Desabilita botao enviar se existir cpf duplicado
    useEffect(() => {
        setDisable(pacientes.some(item => item.cpf === pacienteInfo.cpf))
        const ifExistCpf = () => {
            const filterCpf = pacientes.some(item => item.cpf === pacienteInfo.cpf);
            if (filterCpf === true) {
                setCheckCpf({
                    errorMessageCpf: "Esse CPF já existe",
                });
            } else {
                setCheckCpf({
                    errorMessageCpf: '',
                });
            }
        }
        ifExistCpf();
    }, [pacientes, pacienteInfo]);
    return (
        <Container maxWidth="sm" style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <>
                <h1>Cadastrar paciente</h1>
            </>
            <Form onSubmit={onFormSubmit} className='attached fluid segment'>
                <Form.Field>
                    <label htmlFor='nome'>Nome</label>
                    <input onChange={handleFieldChange} value={pacienteInfo.nome} name='nome' type='text' id='nome' placeholder="Insira seu nome" maxLength='60' pattern="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s]*" title='Não é permite espaço em branco' required />
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field>
                    <label className="margin-top" htmlFor='dataDeNascimento'>Data de Nascimento</label>
                    <input onChange={handleFieldChange} value={pacienteInfo.dataDeNascimento} name='dataDeNascimento' type='text' id='dataDeNascimento' placeholder="Formato: dd/mm/aaaa" pattern='(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/](0[1-9]|1[012])[/](19|20)\d\d' title='Não é permite espaço em branco ou ano menor que 1900' required />
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field>
                    <label className="margin-top" htmlFor='cpf'>CPF</label>
                    <input onChange={handleFieldChange} value={pacienteInfo.cpf} name='cpf' type='text' id='cpf' placeholder="Formato: xxx.xxx.xxx-xx" pattern="\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}-\d{2}" required />
                    <small>{checkCpf.errorMessageCpf}</small>
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field>
                    <label className="margin-top" htmlFor='sexo'>Gênero</label>
                    <select onChange={handleFieldChange} value={pacienteInfo.sexo} id='sexo' name='sexo' required>
                        <option value='' disabled>Escolha uma opção...</option>
                        <option value="Femenino">Feminino</option>
                        <option value="Masculino">Masculino</option>
                        <option value="Não Binario">Não-binário</option>
                        <option value="Outros">Outros</option>
                        <option value="Não Informado">Prefiro não informar</option>
                    </select>
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field>
                    <label className="label" htmlFor='endereco'>Endereço</label>
                    <input onChange={handleFieldChange} value={pacienteInfo.endereco} name='endereco' type='text' id='endereco' placeholder='Insira seu endereço'/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Box className="margin-top" style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-around' }}>
                    <Button type='submit' size="small" variant="contained" color="primary" disabled={disable}>Enviar</Button>
                    <Button type='reset' size="small" variant="outlined">Limpar</Button>
                </Box>
            </Form>
        </Container>

    )
}
export default Cadastrar
```

[image]

**Print LocalStorage**
[image]

I'm using the Storage location to store data and I want to display a success message if the data has been stored or an error message if the data has not been stored.
please help me how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

If you're using

```
localStorage.setItem(keyName, keyValue);
```

For saving your object.
You can add a validation after set the item, something like:

```
if(localStorage.getItem(keyname))
{
    setMessage("success")
} else {
    setMessage("error")
}
```

This way you can verify if the value was stored.

Your message can be stored in an state and showed only when exist.

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState(null)
```

And after you can use that state maybe in a label:

```
{message && <label className="label">{message}</label>}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one state variable for storing boolean

```
const [formSuccess, setFormSuccess] = useState(null)
```

Now, in onFormSubmit

```
const onFormSubmit = (event) => {
  // present logic
  // add if else with that
  if(local storage is success) {
    setFormSuccess(true)
  } else {
    setFormSuccess(false)
  }
};
```

Now in render

```
// just check for formSuccess below <Box>
return (
  {
     !formSuccess ? <show toast fail message> : <show toast success message>
  }
)
```